# No route matches {:action=>"comment", :id=>"1", :controller=>"posts"} on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
<%= form_tag :action => "comment" do %>     
  <%= text_area "comment", "body" %><br /> 
  <%= submit_tag "Comment" %> 
<% end %>
```

I got this error:

```
no route matches found  {:action=>"comment", :id=>"1", :controller=>"posts"
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: `$ rake routes` or `$ bundle exec rake routes` will give you the routes in your app

Answer (score 0):

In order to access route for `{:action=>"comment", :id=>"1", :controller=>"posts"}`

In `routes.rb`, you will need to specify a route as below:

```
post "posts/:id/comment" => "posts#comment"
```

Also, you can run `rake routes` in order to check the available routes for your application.

Answer (score 0):

It is not quite clear from your question, but I guess you have a `comment` method in your `post_controller`. And you want to post to that method to create a new comment.

You will something like this in your `config/routes.rb`:

```
resources :posts
```

And You need to change it to:

```
resources :posts do
  post 'comment', on: :member
end
```

Good read on how the routing works: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html